# Performance analysis of 3 digits sum

Tags: java, performance, complexity

I have a method that finds 3 numbers in an array that add up to a desired number.

```
public static void threeSum(int[] arr, int sum) {
    quicksort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
            for (int k = arr.length - 1; k > j; k--) {
                if ((arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k]) == sum) {
                    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i) + "+" + Integer.toString(j) + "+" + Integer.toString(k) + "="  + sum);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the big O of this method. I have a hard time wrapping my head around this right now. My guess is O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(n<sup>2</sup>logn). But these are complete guesses. I can't prove this. Could someone help me wrap my head around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The running time is O(*n*<sup>3</sup>).  You have three nested loops:

- Approximately *n* iterations of *i*
- For each *i*, approximately *n* iterations of *j*
- For each (*i*, *j*) pair, up to about *n* iterations of *k*.  On average, it take just 0.5 * *n* iterations of *k*, but the constant factor doesn't matter.

Quicksort is generally O(*n* log *n*).  So the total is O(*n* log *n* + 0.5 *n* × *n* × *n*), which is O(*n*<sup>3</sup>).

Since you took the trouble to sort the array, the innermost loop could be replaced by a binary search, which is O(log *n*).  Therefore, an improved algorithm could work in O(*n*<sup>2</sup> log *n*).

Comment: Oh wow Binary search within the inner loop! Never though of that thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This won't change the Big O but the second loop can start at j = i + 1.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for three distinct numbers, or can *i*, *j*, and *k* be the same?  The loop limits suggest that you expect the numbers to be distinct.  However, you don't actually check that the results are distinct.

To be consistent, you should either:

- Make all three loops consider entries from the entire array, or
- Discard solutions where *i* = *j* or where *j* = *k* or where *i* = *k*.

Comment: I figured out the big O of my program. However you made a really good point about the values of the numbers. I am going to look into this!

Comment: O(n^3) for those wondering